# Old javascript routine to change text and background color of cell

Tags: javascript, html

```
function STRover(el) {
    if (lastel != null) STRout(lastel);
    lastel = el;
    lastbg = el.style.backgroundColor;
    el.style.backgroundColor='316AC5';
    el.style.color='FFFFFF';
    el.style.cursor = 'default';
    for(x=0; x < el.childNodes.length; x++) {
        if ( el.hasChildNodes() ) {
            for(xx=0; xx < el.childNodes(x).childNodes.length; xx++) {
                if (el.childNodes(x).childNodes(xx).tagName=="A") {
                    el.childNodes(x).childNodes(xx).style.color="FFFFFF";
                }
            }          
        }
    }    
}
```

This loops over every row in a table, changes the background and text color of each cell. It doesn't work in chrome and i'm sure there is a better / easier way.

seems to be that childNodes isn't supported like this in chrome

> Uncaught TypeError: Property 'childNodes' of object
>   <HTMLTableRowElement> is not a function

Any tips

PS: the application does NOT use jquery so a non jquery solution is preferred.

Comment: Is el.childNodes[x] not useable for your purposes?  Sorry for ignorance, just not used to parentheses for array access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.childNodes` was supported in chrome.

`.childNodes` return an array.
eg:

`document.childNodes` return `[<!DOCTYPE html>, <html>...</html>]`
 `document.childNodes[1]` return `<html>..</html>`

```
for(xx=0; xx < el.childNodes[x].childNodes.length; xx++) {
    if (el.childNodes[x].childNodes[xx].tagName=="A") {
        el.childNodes[x].childNodes[xx].style.color="FFFFFF";
    }
}
```

Comment: Your right it does work, issue was the referenced a href's didnt have an id.